# Passing numbers from a file into a structure

Tags: c, arrays, file, malloc, structure

I've been having problems trying to pass numbers from a file to structure.

The file I'm trying to read has this format:

```
1002 January 287.4
1002 February 22.3
1002 March 51.4
```

This is my code thus far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct RainData{

    int stationID;
    float yearTotal;

};

int main(){

    int n, i, x;
    struct RainData *dataPtr;

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("rain.dat","r");

    if (fptr == NULL){

        printf("Error in opening file\n");

        return 1;

    }

    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n);
    dataPtr = (struct RainData *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct RainData));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){

        for (x = 0; x < 12; x++)

            fscanf(fptr, "%d" "%f", &(*dataPtr).stationID[i], &(*dataPtr).yearTotal[i]);

    }

    fclose(fptr);
    free(dataPtr);

    return 0;

}
```

When I run this, I get a segmentation fault error. I'm pretty sure my mistake is with the malloc, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I'm not sure how to make the variables into arrays by using malloc. I'm also aware of the missing "%s" in the fscanf. The question does not use the months, so I would like to avoid if possible to assign a useless variable just to contain that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your references to the data you're reading aren't correct. It looks like you allocated an array of `struct RainData`, so you should have, for example, `&(dataPtr[i].stationID)` rather than `&(*dataPtr).stationID[i]`. The latter is treating `stationID` like an array inside the structure, which it isn't. And what's the purpose of the `for ( x =...` loop? `x` isn't referenced inside the loop, so you're just reading into the same variables for each loop iteration.

Comment: ... and is there a single `int` value at the *beginning* of the file that dictates the row-count? I ask because there isn't one in your sample data (according to that data coupled with your logic, you should be reading 1002 rows, which I'm confident isn't correct).

Comment: @mbratch Sweet, thanks! There's more to this actually, like how we need to add up the total of 12 months for 5 different stations. The later parts are incomplete.

Comment: Pfft. I'd use none-of-this and fire up Excel with a whitespace delimiter import if that were the case. =P

Comment: I would agree that this is perhaps not the most optimal solution to sort the data but marks are sadly marks :/

Comment: Write a function that reads a year. Let it call a function that reads a month. If the file format has redundant data and it guarantees it (there will always be the same station id 12 times through an entire year), then it's truly redundant data and you can just read the first one and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues. First, as @mbratch pointed out, dataPtr is an array of struct, so you must use hte correct subscript to refer to that and then use the "." to refer to its member. Second, your file contains rows in the format of "%d %s %f", so you need to update the fscanf as well. Third, you need to add the total number of rows at the top since that is wehre you are reading the value of n from. Lastly, not sure, why you have x going from 0 to 12 -- you can delete that.

Try this main code:

```
int n, i, x;
struct RainData *dataPtr;
FILE *fptr;
char temp_str[100];

fptr = fopen("rain.dat","r");
if (fptr == NULL){
    printf("Error in opening file\n");
    return 1;
}

fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n);
dataPtr = (struct RainData *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct RainData));
printf("n is %d\n", n);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    fscanf(fptr, "%d %s %f", &dataPtr[i].stationID, temp_str, &dataPtr[i].yearTotal);
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%d \t %f\n", dataPtr[i].stationID, dataPtr[i].yearTotal);
}

fclose(fptr);
free(dataPtr);
return 0;
```

With this rain.dat file:

```
3
1002 January 287.4
1002 February 22.3
1002 March 51.4
```